Is there a way to validate array keys?
I have checkboxes with name category[{{$category->id}}]. I'd like to validate the category id for these checkboxes whether it is a valida id or something else. I found that arrays can be validated this way:
    $input = $request->validate([
        'category' => 'nullable|array',
        'category.*' => 'integer|min:1',
        'keywords' => 'nullable|string|min:1|max:2000'
    ]);

The problem that I want to validate the keys, not the values. Is there a way to do so with Laravel validation rules?
For example the input is something like {"category": {"1": "on", "8": "on", ...}} in JSON format and I want to check whether 1 and 8 are category ids or at least they are integers. Not sure if the validator is capable of doing this. If not, then I'll send a feature request for it.

Maybe something like this? https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#rule-required-array-keys

You can also - I think - use https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation

@inf3rno, "The problem that I want to validate the keys, not the values" -- Here did you mean that you want validate category[{{$category->id}}] for each checkbox ? Can you please clarify?

@inf3rno , Based on my understanding I have posted my answer, please check and let me know your feedback. Thanks

@Subha Yes, the input is something like {category: ['1': 'on', 8: 'on', ...]}. I want to validate the 1, 8 there whether they are real category ids.

@CornelRaiu As far as I understand the required array keys does not solve this, since the array keys are the ids we want to validate, while required array keys needs a known list of keys.

@CornelRaiu My workaround would be a FormRequest which prepares the data if this is not possible with current Laravel. I am just curious if this is possible out of the box without preparing the data.

It's unclear why you took an incorrect answer, appended your own correct answer to it, and then marked it accepted. You are aware you can self-answer a question?

@miken32 It is different, since we are talking about Laravel 11.

There's nothing relevant to this question that is changed by the version. The answer you tacked on is precisely the same approach outlined in one of the answers to the duplicate target from 4 years previous.

@miken32 Okay, then probably this is a duplicate.

To validate the checkboxes with names like category[{{$category->id}}] in Laravel, where each checkbox name is tied to a specific category-ID , you can use  the exists rule to ensure that the category-ID exists in the database.
Do this. I think it will resolve your issue...
$input = $request->validate([
    'category' => 'nullable|array',
    'category.*' => 'integer|exists:categories,id' //assumed `categories` is respected table in DB
]);

For detailed information you can check the Specifying a Custom Column Name section of the official-docs.
As of validating the keys, you need to prepare the request. The best way is moving the whole thing into a FormRequest and use the prepareForValidation method.
class ProductSearchRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected function prepareForValidation(): void {
        $this->merge([
            'category' => isset($this->category)?array_keys($this->category):[],
            'keywords' => isset($this->keywords)?str_replace('%', '', $this->keywords):''
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'category' => 'nullable|array',
            'category.*' => 'integer|min:1|exists:categories,id',
            'keywords' => 'nullable|string|min:0|max:2000'
        ];
    }
}


Isn't exists for values instead of keys? Note: I edited my question.

@inf3rno, actually exists:categories,id -- This ensures that each selected value corresponds to a valid category ID from the categories table by checking against the id column.

As far as I understand exists would check in the case of {"category": {"1": "on"}} if "on" is a valid id. But correct me if I am wrong.

@inf3rno, that is correct. But based on the condition that you provided this validation can also be done. But I need some time since currently I am outside and replying you from phone.

@inf3rno, Okay , For example the input is something like {"category": {"1": "on", "8": "on", ...}} in JSON format and I want to check whether 1 and 8 are category ids or at least they are integers. --- as per this condition the above solution will work ,cz
1) it will check if the ID has a matching record, so if the ID has no matching record it will throw validation error by default.
Check this link also https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#basic-usage-of-exists-rule

@inf3rno, You can at least try the above solution with some testing and let me know if it is working. pass 1, 8 and some unmatched ID like 7 or 3.

I edited your answer. I don't think there is an out of the box solution for validating keys in scenarios like this, so it is easier to prepare the data instead.

Yes I checked it & no doubt that is the better one or probably the best approach to solve the issue. Thank you.
